# Efficient way for calculating the sum of all products of m elements in vector.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let's introduce a bit of notation:

Say we had a vector $x = (x_1, x_2, x_3,\dots,x_n)^{T}$, then

$$\Sigma^{1}x=\sum_{i}^{n} x_{i}$$
$$\Sigma^{2}x=\sum_{i}^{n}\sum_{j}^{n} x_{i}x_{j}$$
$$\Sigma^{3}x=\sum_{i}^{n}\sum_{j}^{n}\sum_{k}^{n} x_{i}x_{j}x_{k}$$
$$\vdots$$

Is there an easy (or more efficient) number-theory-like way of doing $\Sigma^m x$?
Or Is there a fast algorithm for calculating it?

I've realised for example, that when $n = 2$, $\Sigma^m x$ follows pascal's triangle:

$$\Sigma^{1}x = x_1 + x_2$$
$$\Sigma^{2}x = x_1^2 + 2x_1x_2 + x_2^2$$
$$\Sigma^{3}x = x_1^3 + 3x_1^2x_2 + 3x_1x_2^2 + x_2^3$$
$$\Sigma^{4}x = x_1^4 + 4x_1^3x_2 + 6x_1^2x_2^2 + 4x_1x_2^3 + x_2^4$$

Comment: The calculation $\sum \sum x_ix_j$ has $n^2$ products and  $n$ additions.  The calculation $(\sum x_i)^2$ has only $n$ additions and $1$ product.

Comment: Oh, so: $\Sigma^mx = (\sum x)^m$?

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: How interesting, innit?

Answer (score 1):

So to answer my own question, as an extension of WA Don's answer, it's easy to see that

$$\Sigma^mx = (\sum x)^m$$

Since the opposite is true for:

$$(a+b)^m = \Sigma^{m} (a, b)^T$$

and

$$(a+b+c)^m = \Sigma^{m} (a, b, c)^T$$

and so on.